# Communicate puredata with Arduino over Serial. Unable to connect to the same port for stablishing communication

Tags: arduino, serial-port, puredata

As the title indicates, I need to create a bridge betweeen pd and arduino UNO but I can't get it to work.
I need to start an arduino process after receiving a message from my computer through puredata, using the comport object.
Since comport object in pd doesn't allow me to connect to the port used by arduino (listed trough "devices" message in pd) I don't understand how to stablish a communication between them.

```
[comport]: could not open device COM3:
failure(5) ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Arduino is connected to the computer by usb cable.

Comment: "*I dont understand why my question**s** are being systematically downvoted*" -- You exaggerate. Just one (1) downvote on only one question in the past year is not a trend. You also don't seem to understand what a ["good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for this site entails. "*[U]nable-to-connect ...*" and "*I can't get it to work*" are inadequate descriptions for a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If been able to sort it out using in arduino.

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1);
```

And then referring to the serial with the variable used, mySerial, in this case.
Since this moment, when I was trying to do it using a basic included Serial communication, without library, I was not able to find the needed port free in puredata. Now it seems to work well, I cannot figure it out why not before.